# Why can "-Wobjc-literal-conversion" be ignored by the preprocessor?

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-data, clang-static-analyzer

I had a small bug in my project probably related to `-Wobjc-literal-conversion`.

There's a Swift class which is later called in ObjcC code:

```
@objc(SomeClass)
public final class SomeClass: NSManagedObject {
}

extension SomeClass {
    @NSManaged public var someProperty: Bool    
}
```

And then somewhere in the Objc code there was a bug like this:

```
someClassObj.someProperty = @NO;
```

Here, `@NO` is a literal of `String` type. And it seems a literal is converted to `true`. So we had a bug.

So I've tried to treat `-Wobjc-literal-conversion` as error. But it doesn't work neither in the project settings:
[image]

nor with `#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wobjc-literal-conversion"` at the top of the Objc file.

I didn't try to create a toy project, because this bug can be related to CoreData, so it's time-consuming.

Do you have any ideas/suggestions how to check why this warning doesn't work? I've tried to create other errors in this file intentionally - the preprocessor works in such case.

Comment: “`@NO` is a literal of `String` type” ... No it's not. It is a `NSNumber` literal. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: @Rob Ah, of course — `Bool` imported _to Obj-C_ is `BOOL`, so this is invalid. Deleted my misleading comment.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant warning is `-Wint-conversion`.

[image]

---

To create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you do not need some complicated CoreData project. In your blank project, define a Swift class:

```swift
@objc class Foo: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var bar: Bool
}
```

And then write code to update that from Objective-C:

```objectivec
//  Baz.m

#import "Baz.h"
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"

@implementation Baz
- (void)qux:(Foo *)foo {
    foo.bar = @NO;
}
@end
```

When you compile that, you'll get the the warning you expected.

[image]

If you go to the “Report navigator”, click on the build, and then expand the warning, you will see the compiler’s warning code:

```
/.../MyApp/Baz.m:14:13: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') from 'NSNumber *' [-Wint-conversion]
    foo.bar = @NO;
            ^ ~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Once you know it is the “integer to pointer conversion” error, it is easy to find it in the build settings.